# out of action function conditions in classes

Tags: c#, function, class, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write classes and make them contain a conditions. I wrote all classes and functions correctly but my conditions aren't work. For example I try to make one function check if phoneNumber is equal 10 or not. but the condition is not work. this is function

```
    public int PhoneNumber {
        set { phoneNumber = value; }
        get
        {
            if(phoneNumber.ToString().Length < 10 || phoneNumber.ToString().Length > 10)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
                return phoneNumber;
        }
    }
```

phoneNumber is type `internal`. when I enter "12345" It shown.
In addition I want to switch `return 0;` to a error message but I couldn't because return have to be int not string. Is there way I can use it to show  MESSAGE while condition isn't correct.

Comment: An int is not able to hold 10 digits. You have to use a long or keep it a string. Phonenumbers are often treated as strings.

Comment: `int` is not a good type to store a phone number. 1. `Int32.MaxValue` is only `2147483647` so you cannot store `3-333-333-333` 2. Phone numbers can have `+` in them or start with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( phoneNumber.ToString().Length != 10) {
   throw new Exception("Phone number must have 10 digits");
} else return number;
```

here you throw an exception if someone try to enter invalid phone number, in the code that use it , you can sue try/catch (to display your error message)